# Is ClassLoader guaranteed to find class from same package

Tags: java, classloader

I have package a with classes B and C in it. Is `B.class.getClassLoader().loadClass('a.C');` always going to return a valid Class?

Comment: the (built in) classloader is guaranteed to find a valid class in the classpath.  what exactly is your question?

Comment: It depends if C is available in the classpath of the ClassLoader. Its package is irrelevant.

Comment: @jtahlborn make your comment an answer and I will accept it.